# Initializing a class in another function

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

I have a code that if simplified would look like this:

```
void foo(MyObject& y){
    int 2;
    MyObject y(2);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    MyObject x;
    foo(x);
    x.run();
}
```

However, I get the error message "error: declaration of 'MyObject y' shadows a parameter. Note that foo() is originally a much more complicated function, i.e., I would rather not copy and paste foo's code to main (although it looks very possible in the above example). What I would like to do here is that to pass MyObject x to foo in main(), initialize x in foo(), and call x.run() in main.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't initialize an object twice. What you can do is assign it a different value:

```
void foo(MyObject& y){
    int n = 2;
    y = MyObject(n);
}
```

Alternatively, write a function that initialized an object and returns it:

```
MyObject foo(){
    int n = 2;
    return MyObject(n);
}

MyObject m(foo());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `foo()` does not do what you think, it has a parameter called `y` and a local variable also called `y`; they do not refer to the same object.

```
void foo(MyObject& y){
    int 2;
    MyObject y(2);  // This is a new instance of MyObject independent of the parameter y
}
```

Solutions include:

- Adding a "modifier" method to `MyObject` to change its state `y.set(2)`,
- Constructing a temporary `MyObject` and assigning it to y: `y = MyObject(2)`,
- Returning a copy of a temporary object: `return MyObject(2)` (making the reference parameter unnecessary).

These last two require that your class has suitable copy semantics, which may require a copy constructor or assignment operator to be defined if the object is not trivial.